# Service proven to exist but doesn't show anywhere

Tags: windows-10, services

I am able to start or stop one particular service, but it's not listed in `services.msc` or even if any other way of querying services is used (`sc queryex`, `gsv`, `Get-Service` without arguments, etc.). Everything is done as admin, nothing works.

PowerShell's `Get-Service` followed by the name of the service works and shows the information.

[image: command prompt with commands used]

`net start vmnetbridge` and `net stop vmnetbridge` cause the service to start and stop, respectively, but an `sc query` through `find` produces nothing:

```
sc queryex type= service state= all | find /i "bridge"
```

I am using Windows 10. Is this a service? If so, why does it not show in the usual places?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The VMware Bridge Protocol service isn't the same kind of service as, say, the Print Spooler. Normal services run in a process of their own or in a shared service hosting process (`svchost.exe`). `vmnetbridge`, however, is actually a kernel-mode driver:

```
C:\Windows\System32>sc query vmnetbridge

SERVICE_NAME: vmnetbridge
        TYPE               : 1  KERNEL_DRIVER
        STATE              : 4  RUNNING
                                (STOPPABLE, NOT_PAUSABLE, IGNORES_SHUTDOWN)
        WIN32_EXIT_CODE    : 0  (0x0)
        SERVICE_EXIT_CODE  : 0  (0x0)
        CHECKPOINT         : 0x0
        WAIT_HINT          : 0x0
```

The Services snap-in for MMC only shows standard services (`WIN32_OWN_PROCESS` or `WIN32_SHARE_PROCESS`), though the Service Control Manager deals with all kinds. To get entries for this service in your `sc queryex` command, you need to change your `type=` filter to `type= driver` or `type= all`.

Further reading: [Numeric constants related to services](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/103000), [the services reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms685141(v=vs.85).aspx)